# How to insert a blank Facebook comment?

Tags: facebook-comments

[This](https://www.facebook.com/memeskilledmyfamily/posts/1177909065586454?comment_id=1177950175582343) seems to be a "completely" blank Facebook comment. Facebook does not accept comments consisting solely of newlines or spaces, but accepts a soft hyphen comment. However, unlike a soft hyphen comment, the one in the link doesn't seem to be , and leaves no trace in html (the value 
`<span class="UFICommentBody"></span>` is empty). What's the trick behind this?
(I've tried inserting a zero-width space or a 1x1 image and it didn't work, but maybe I'm doing it wrong).